# categorize expense with a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dictionary

I have an dataframe expense

| Date | Libellé | Prix | Catégorie | Sous-catégorie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 | CB Darty xxxxxx | 100 | ? | ? |
| 04/09/22 | CB Restau Macdo xxx | 10 | ? | ? |
| 01/10/22 | VIR SALAIRE MOMO xxxx | 10000000 | ? | ? |
| 04/11/22 | VIR TUTU | 100 | ? | ? |

And another dataframe 2 which do the link betwwen categorie, sous-categorie and some keyword

| Catégorie | Sous-catégorie | Keyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Courant | Alimentation | Macdo, KFC, Burger_King |
| Courant | Loisirs | Darty, UGC, Pathé |
| Pro | Revenus | Salaire, Momo |

I would like in python, for each row in dataframe expense fill categorie and sous-categorie in fonction of the keyword that wen can find in the libellé column and using the second dataframe.
I'm beginner in python and i don't know how to begin.

One option, in my opinion, is to do a for loop on row of dataframe2 and for each keyword in colum keyword, search in the libellé column of dataframe expense and in case of a match, add the category and sub-category to the row in expense. But it's going to be very slow and maybe there is a better way to do with python.
I saw on stack overflow, some other question on this topic but none with category, sub-category and keyword

Comment: What if the second dataframe had a fourth row that has the keyword `Darty` ? Which row (*i.e* Catégorie and Sous-catégorie) you have to choose/fill for the date `01/01/22` in the first dataframe ?

Comment: Can you create a copy-pastable version of both tables?

Comment: Also, what if `CB` and `Darty` are in different rows of `df2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear how you want to handle *"1-lib:n-keywords" and vice-versa* but you can still try this :

```
def tkn(s):
    import re
    return set(re.split(",?\s+", s.lower()))
        
matches = {
    kw: lib for kw, lib in product(df2["Keyword"], df1["Libellé"])
    if set(tkn(kw)).intersection(tkn(lib)) # is it sufficient ?
}
        
target = ["Catégorie", "Sous-catégorie"]

out = (
    pd.merge(
        df1.drop(columns=target, errors="ignore"), df2[target],
        left_on="Libellé", right_on=df2["Keyword"].map(matches), how="left"
    )
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

       Date                Libellé      Prix Catégorie Sous-catégorie
0  01/01/22        CB Darty xxxxxx       100   Courant        Loisirs
1  04/09/22    CB Restau Macdo xxx        10   Courant   Alimentation
2  01/10/22  VIR SALAIRE MOMO xxxx  10000000       Pro        Revenus
3  04/11/22               VIR TUTU       100       NaN            NaN

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: What mean the match expression  kw: lib for kw, lib in product ?

Comment: I mean by that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77729042/categorize-expense-with-a-dataframe/77729248?noredirect=1#comment137032872_77729042) comment and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77729042/categorize-expense-with-a-dataframe/77729248?noredirect=1#comment137033206_77729042) one. Can you answer that, please ?

Comment: the df 1 will be an extract of bank account (import excel) and the "libellé" column is the description of the operation (written by the bank).  Depending of the month, the df1 can contains 10, 20, 50 or more row of operations and to avoid to categorize manually  expense which occur frequently (for exemple, fnac, carrefour, superu), i created a df2. i will filled manually df2 with category / subcategory and associated keyword that appear regurlarly in df1 libellé column. I hope that it will help you to understand more clearly what i wand to do. (Sorry for my level in english )

Comment: in df2, one keyword (fnac, darty, etc;..) wille be only assiated to one pair category / sub-category. for you question, "CB" will not be in df2 because it's too vague.